# Using Firebase v9, how can I add the user to the user collection upon logging in with gmail?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I add a user to the `users` collection logging in with Gmail?
I tried the `addUser` but it does not work. I'm quite new to Firebase v9

```
//firebase
    import { signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
    import { auth, signInWithGoogle, db } from "../../Firebase/utils";
    import { doc, setDoc, collection } from "firebase/firestore";

const Login = (props) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const addUser = async () => {
    const userRef = doc(db, "users", auth.currentUser);
    setDoc(userRef);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    addUser();
  }, []);

  const googleHandler = async () => {
    signInWithGoogle.setCustomParameters({ prompt: "select_account" });
    signInWithPopup(auth, signInWithGoogle)
      .then((result) => {
        // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
        const token = credential.accessToken;
        // The signed-in user info.
        const user = result.user;
        // redux action? --> dispatch({ type: SET_USER, user });
        addUser();
        console.log(auth.currentUser, "login page");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle Errors here.
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // The email of the user's account used.
        const email = error.email;
        // The AuthCredential type that was used.
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
        // ...
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
        <form>
           <Button onClick={googleHandler}>Login with Gmail</Button>
        </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

These are my package.json just to be sure:

[image]

This is what the `console.log(auth.currentUser)` shows:
[image]

**UPDATE:**

```
const addUser = async (userId) => {
    const userRef = doc(db, "users", userId);
    return await setDoc(userRef, { ...data });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    addUser();
  }, []);

  const googleHandler = async () => {
    signInWithGoogle.setCustomParameters({ prompt: "select_account" });
    signInWithPopup(auth, signInWithGoogle)
      .then(async (result) => {
        // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
        const token = credential.accessToken;
        // The signed-in user info.
        const user = result.user;
        // redux action? --> dispatch({ type: SET_USER, user });
        // addUser();

        const { isNewUser } = getAdditionalUserInfo(result);
        if (isNewUser) {
          await addUser(user.uid);
        } else {
          console.log("User already exists");
        }
      })

      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle Errors here.
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // The email of the user's account used.
        const email = error.email;
        // The AuthCredential type that was used.
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
        // ...
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `doc()` function takes Firestore instance as first argument and the rest are path segments (strings) so you cannot pass `currentUser` object there. Also there might be a chance that `auth.currentUser`. You can use `isNewUser` property to check if the user has just signed up or is logging in again and then add the document. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
signInWithPopup(auth, signInWithGoogle)
  .then(async (result) => {
    const user = result.user;
    
    const { isNewUser } = getAdditionalUserInfo(result)
    if (isNewUser) {
      await addUser(user.uid); 
    } else {
      console.log("User already exists")
    }
})

const addUser = async (userId) => {
  const userRef = doc(db, "users", userId);
  return await setDoc(userRef, {...data});
};
```

Comment: Will this also work since I would only have 1 user? Since I won't be using where the user can register accounts

Comment: @RavenousRed if you are creating a new account the document will be added else no. So for every new user, addUser() will be called once. Also updated answer to pass data in setDoc()

Comment: I'm getting an error that says `getAdditionalUserInfo` is undefined and the `addUser` as undefined as well

Comment: @RavenousRed you need to add `import { getAdditionalUserInfo } from "firebase/auth"` and addUser is the function defined by you in original code, I just modified it.

Comment: now it says that `data` is undefined. I posted the updated one

Comment: @RavenousRed replace data with whatever you want to pass in the document? For example: `return await setDoc(userRef, { docAddedAt: Date.now() })`

Comment: I forgot to mention that the `uid` is also being saved in the firestore in separate letter. Like it has the field `0: D` then `1:m` and so on.

Comment: I doubt if you have have spread operator `...` on the userId

Comment: I was able to fix it with this `id: userId`